# data table view is not refreshing properly jQuery ajax MVC call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to filter the data from a table in MVC application using jQuery ajax call.

Below is the code,

```
 function getAllUserRoleCompany() {

    var url = '@Url.Action("GetAllUserRoleCompany", "UserRoleCompany")';
    Var Organisation = "";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { Organisation: Organisation},

        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#dataTables-example').html(data);
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
}
```

The table is getting filtered properly with successful controller call.
The issue here is in the view as it is not getting loaded properly. It is getting loaded in the previous table I guess as it still shows the pagination from the previous table, shown below

[image]

Here is my partial view I am calling,

```
            @Html.Partial("pv_UserRoleCompany", Model)
```

Please guide.

Comment: You need to shown the relevant code, including the view and the partial, and the controller method

Answer (score 0):

Once after filtered results, if you want to replace the `DataTable` in your `View` then clear the existing rows with `html("")` and replace with new rows,

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#dataTables-example').html("").html(data);
},
```